# Como faço para verificar se o meu input do tipo file está vazio em PHP?

Tags: php, html, array

```
<form action="teste1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  

<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="file" name="arquivos[]" multiple>
```

```
<?php
$photo=$_FILES["arquivos"];
if(empty($_FILES["arquivos"]["name"])){
    echo "vazio";
}

?>
```

Tentei colocar a variável `photo` no lugar de `files` mas dá a mesma coisa.

Comment: Não seria `if (empty($_FILES))`?

Comment: nao ta funcionando com o tipo file, eu fiz com tipo text e funciona blz if(empty($_FILES['arquivos']['name'])){
  echo "vazio";
 }

Comment: Ja tentou tirar os colchetes? porque você está enviando um array assim

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira que vejo para tratar envio de arquivos, quando o mesmo não é enviado é usando a `key error` do `array` gerado pela `$_FILES`, pegando erro tipo 4, `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` que quer dizer que nenhum arquivo foi carregado.

```
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"];
if ($arquivo["error"] == 4) {
    return false;
}
```

Podemos fazer a verificação de forma mais explicita, assim o código fica mais legível, ou seja, ao bater o olho você já vai saber o que significa aquele retorno (de erro).

```
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"];
if ($arquivo["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    return false;
}
```

Leia mais sobre os tipos de erros aqui: [Error Messages Explained](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

**EDIT:**

`if (empty($_FILES)){...}` ou `if ((empty($_FILES["arquivo"])){...}` não vai funcionar pois o `array` gerado nunca é vazio sempre tem pelo meno a chave erro preenchida com o código do erro. Isso funcionaria se o campo de fato não existisse, por exemplo, se eles estivesse com atributo `disabled`.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode verificar se o tamanho da primeira entrada é maior que `0`, dessa forma saberá se tem arquivos para fazer upload

```
if ($_FILES['arquivos']['size'][0] > 0) {
    echo 'Contém arquivos';
} else {
    echo 'Vazio';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Tente assim:

```
<form action="teste1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="file" name="arquivos" multiple>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['arquivos']))
{
$photo=$_POST["arquivos"];
if(empty($_FILES["arquivos"]["name"])){
echo "vazio";
}
}

?>
```

Não deveria ter um `<input type="submit" value="Enviar">` aí?

Comment: Qual o objetivo da verificação `isset($_GET['arquivos'])`?

Comment: nao, continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Eu sempre usei `isset($_GET['exemplo'])` para fazer meu algorítmo "rodar"

Comment: @IzaacMendes tem alguma coisa nas variáveis que criou em php que não está encaixando, como o `name` dentro de `arquivos`

Comment: @IzaacMendes eu editei o php, talvez agora funcione